# Export index definitions in underlying collection when dumping views?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I have a database for development from which I only need to dump a subset of the fields, but all documents. So I created a view on the collection I need and `monogodump`ed the view. Unfortunately, the underlying collection had indexes defined which were not rebuilt when I `mongorestore`d the collections from the dump, because the index definitions were not dumped along with the data, apparently because they are defined for the collection, not for the view.

Is there a way to have the index definitions of the underlying collection dumped along with the data from the view?

Of course I can manually tell MongoDB to rebuild the indexes on the restored target collections, but that seems error-prone.

The fact that some indexes are on fields that are not part of the view may be a problem or even a blocker.

Comment: mongodump will create index definitions automatically, if the collection has indexes.  Views are treated as collections, but have no indexes.  I assume you backed up a view, and not the underlying collection, and not the entire database.  Try backing up the entire database and upon using mongorestore you will see your indexes have been restored too.

Comment: What does the last line of the description mean? _The fact that some indexes are on fields that are not part of the view may be a problem or even a blocker._

Comment: @barrypicker I understand that, hence the question.

Comment: @user20042973 In case it is actually possible to dump the index definition along with the view, it might be a problem that some index definitions are for fields that are not included in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the direct answer to your question is: No, `mongodump` will not pull index definitions from the source collection(s) associated with the view. Some degree of manual intervention or a change of approach is going to be needed here.

The specific approach you take depends on your specific constraints and goals. A few general things come to mind for consideration:

- If the data isn't actually moving clusters, then perhaps `$merge` by itself would be sufficient in moving the subset of fields to a different collection. The rest of this answer assumes that this is not the case and that you do intend to actually move the data to a different cluster.
- `$merge` may still be of interest even if you are moving the data since you could use that on the source cluster (combined with a script to copy indexes) and then run `mongodump` on that new collection instead. It's an extra data copy, but allows a script to programmatically recreate the indexes directly which should help prevent human error.
- If you did continue with the current approach mentioned in the question, you could use a similar script to grab the index definitions (and then have them recreated).
- Another thing you *could* do is run a second `mongodump` against the source collection with [a --query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--query) that didn't match any documents (eg `{ _id: 'missing' }`). The outcome would be a dump that doesn't contain any data, only index definitions. Those index definitions are just JSON text, so you could update the namespace and then combine it with the data dumped from the view to be restored together.

The specifics of the script to copy indexes mentioned in a couple of the alternatives depend a little bit on the specifics. But it would basically leverage the `db.collection.getIndexes()` helper to gather a list of existing indexes and then iterate over them to generate the appropriate command(s) to create the new ones.

I also want to address these statements:

> The fact that some indexes are on fields that are not part of the view may be a problem or even a blocker.
> it might be a problem that some index definitions are for fields that are not included in the view.

From MongoDB's perspective, there is no issue with creating indexes on fields that do not exist. Since it has a flexible schema, new fields could be added at any point. The fact that indexes aren't dumped for views is really more related to the fact that the views are not materialized. Now if some of those indexes are not appropriate for the transformed data (which doesn't have all of the fields from the original data), then of course you should consider dropping (or not creating) those indexes.

Comment: Merge followed by a dump is probably the best way to go about it. The `mongodump` with `--query` might be faster but the two steps seem like the cleaner approach.